# curl - request with json object and file to Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, curl

I need post file and JSON object to API (Ruby On Rails) by curl in one request.
My request looks like this:

```
curl --data @file.pdf -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data"  -X POST -d '{"document":{"name":"file name"}}' http://localhost:3000/api/documents
```

But Rails parse it bad. Params on the server:

```
Parameters: {"{\"document\":{\"name\":\"file name\"}}"=>nil}
```

Where is problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass `multipart/form-data` (as you specify), not a JSON string. Try this:

```
-d 'document[name]=file name'
```

Result on my machine:

```
Parameters: {"document"=>{"name"=>"file name"}}
```